# Why can't I send my files to the Trash?

Tags: finder, permission, trash

When I try to delete some items, whether from the keyboard (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>) or by dragging to the Trash on the dock, I get a message informing me that I can only permanently delete the item.

Why is that? How can I change that? (Is it a permissions issue?)

Comment: Please run the command `ls -leO@d ~ ~/.Trash` and post the results -- that might help show exactly what needs fixing.

Comment: It reports this: `drwxr-xr-x+ 37 Moshe  staff  - 1258 Mar 27 13:26 /Users/Moshe
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------  18 Moshe  staff  -  612 Apr  1 14:49 /Users/Moshe/.Trash`

Comment: That looks entirely normal -- apparently it's not permissions on either your .Trash or home folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you suspect it's a permissions issue (and permissions can be the cause of a great many problems in OSX), open Disk Utility (/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility.app) and select 'Repair Permissions' from the First Aid tab.  It will output permissions problems if finds and fixes.

Comment: This worked! It found a bunch of permissions settings and fixed them.

Answer (score 1):

The Finder can't create or manage trashbins over network shares, and will tell you that.

Comment: It does the same for files on my desktop.

Comment: Interesting.   It *might* then be permissions:  open a Terminal, type `ls -ld ~/.Trash`.  It should look something like `drwx------  46 allbery  staff  1564 Mar 30 23:50 .Trash/` (with your username instead of mine).

Comment: So how would I fix permissions? With that command?

Comment: Depends on what's broken, but simple permissions issues would be `sudo chown $USER ~/.Trash; sudo chmod 700 ~/.Trash`.

Comment: Nope, still wants to trash things permanently.

Comment: Make sure that you have rw access to your home folder. Select your home folder and choose RMB->`Get Info`.

Comment: @Mspasov - I have R&W access to my home folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link. It provides a number of options for you to try.

http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/trash.html

> A variety of issues can result in
>   making it difficult or impossible to
>   either move files to, or empty, the
>   Trash in Mac® OS X. This FAQ, derived
>   from our book Troubleshooting Mac OS
>   X, covers the following Trash-related
>   topics:
>
> [snip]

Comment: This community appreciates a little extra bit of info or something like that to make answers more than just a link. Can you add some such tidbit here? Thanks!